# Excel VBA multiple change events causing insufficient stacking space

Tags: excel, vba, events, onchange, worksheet

I'm making a form to calculate the price rooms we rent out. Among others this cost is based on the arrival and departure date. You can see a screenshot of the form below;
 - "Aankomst" (the first date) means "Arrival"
 - "Vertrek" (the second date) means "Departure"

As you can see, I added buttons to respectively decrease or increase the dates. I also made sure that impossible values would be rectified. The departure date can never be equal or lower than the arrival date. When trying to decrease the departure date, or increase the arrival date, this is triggered when wrong.

[image: Input form]

When inputting values manually, this check does not occur. A bit of searching learned me I could do this with a change event macro.

I wrote this bit of code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


If Target.Address = "$B$5" And Range("$b$5").Value + 1 >= Range("$b$6").Value Then
Range("$b$6").Value = Range("$b$5").Value + 1
End If

If Target.Address = "$B$6" And Range("$b$6").Value - 1 <= Range("$b$5").Value Then
Range("$b$5").Value = Range("$b$6").Value - 1
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

B5 is the cell containing the arrival date, b6 is the cell containing the departure date. When triggered, this macro should check both which cell was changed (b5 or b6) and if the arr. date is equal to or higher than the dep. date. And if so, automatically change the other cell (the one that was not manually changed).

Now when I omit the second if-statement, it works just fine. If I omit the second if-statement, it works fine as well. When both statements are active, it bugs everytime. I get a prompt saying 'insufficient stacking space' (translated from dutch).

I've tried this code as well, using case:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Range("b6").Value - 1 <= Range("b5").Value Then

Select Case Target.Address(0, 0)
   Case "b5": Range("vertrek").Value = Range("aankomst").Value + 1
   Case "b6": Range("aankomst").Value = Range("vertrek").Value - 1
End Select

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

...but also without success, same error. When I debug, I can see that the date was indeed changed if necessary, so I presume I somehow create an infinite loop or smth and that causes Excel to bug.

Does anyone know where my error lies or anyone aware of another method to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protect against re-raising the same event over and over:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Address = "$B$5" And Range("$b$5").Value + 1 >= Range("$b$6").Value Then
        Range("$b$6").Value = Range("$b$5").Value + 1
    End If

    If Target.Address = "$B$6" And Range("$b$6").Value - 1 <= Range("$b$5").Value Then
        Range("$b$5").Value = Range("$b$6").Value - 1
    End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```